# How can i align button with input in a div, using CSS.

Tags: html, css

Not using bootstrap, I am building it from scratch, that is why I have an image as a background to a button. Any other suggestions on that?
My HTML & CSS:

```css
.searchcontainer .content{  
    border-color: rgb(76, 158, 21);
    width: 60%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    
}
#askinfo {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 14px;  
    font-size-adjust: initial;
    top:0;
    margin:1%;
    height:auto;
    padding: 1%;
    width: 24%;
    
}
.content button {
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(76, 158, 21, 0);    
    max-width: 4%;
    height: 100%; 
 }
 .content button img {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;  
}
```

```html
<div class="searchcontainer">
        <form class="content animate">
            <input type="text" id="askinfo" placeholder="From?" required>
           
                    <button>
                        <img src="replace.png">
                    </button>
            
            <input type="text" id="askinfo" placeholder="To?" required>
            <input type="text" id="askinfo" placeholder="When?" required>
            
                <button>        
                    <img src="search.png">
                </button>  
        </form>
    </div>
```

The buttons are always sticking to the top of the div, I want them to be in a line with the input fields.
I do not know that the problem is.
Thanks!

Comment: Dont use image tag inside a button instead use background-image css property. If you want to use icon use font icons or svgs instead

Comment: This is not part of the question, but I'm pretty sure it's a bad idea to have multiple elements with the same ID. In this case, "askinfo". Consider changing that to a class. As I said, this has nothing to do with the issue which has been correctly answered above.

Comment: What is the difference? If you can explain it to me? They have the same ID because I'll use them only together in my css, I won't use document.getElementById on them. Is there any other reason why i should prefer class over ID? 
Thanks.

Comment: Using ID for a single element and using classes for multiple elements are the "best practices" for web design. 

Does this mean what you're doing won't work? No.

It's just best practice to use classes when applying styles/events to multiple elements on a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the content of the image you're loading inside the button element. Try loading that image with a background-image property in the css like this.

```
.content:nth-child(2) {
    background: url("./replace.png") no-repeat
 }

.content:nth-child(5) {
    background: url("./search.png") no-repeat
 }
```

Then remove that image from the button in the html

Answer (score 0):

You can align the button using CSS

```
#askinfo {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its caused by the image. You should try to use a background image in css instead of a image in HTML.